# Wait for Base Onload event

Tags: asp.net, async-await, webforms

Trying to make use of Async await in ASP.Net Webforms.
Consider I have a base user control as below

```
public class BaseUserControl :UserControl
{
    public int SomeBaseValue { get; set; }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        Page.RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(PageLoadAsync));
    }

    public async Task PageLoadAsync()
    {
        SomeBaseValue = await GetBaseValueFromDB();
    }
}
```

An EmployeeUserControl that derives from BaseUserControl

```
public class EmployeeUserControl : BaseUserControl
{
    public int SomeDerivedValue { get; set; }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e); //Want this method to wait for the completion of base class's async method
        
        SomeDerivedValue = base.SomeBaseValue * 2;
    }

}
```

So the derived class has a property named SomeDerivedValue that depends on the base class's
SomeBaseValue, so I want, when the Derived Class base.OnLoad is called it should wait for the BaseUserControl's OnLoad method completion including the completion of Async Method.

As of now the execution doesnt wait for the completion of Async method, so the SomeBasevalue  is null when it executes the line  `SomeDerivedValue = base.SomeBaseValue * 2;`

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You might think adding a [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource) to `BaseUserControl` would solve it, but it would (probably - haven't tried) deadlock the page.

Web Forms only supports `async`/`await` in `PageAsyncTask`s. Those respect the recommended lifetime for page processing.

[Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET 4.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45)